# Windows 10 Disk Problems: No boot options work

Tags: windows

Something is wrong with my Windows 10 PC. On startup, I'm told it's repairing disk which runs endlessly without doing anything

I then created a recovery drive on a USB stick from a different computer

On startup of this, I boot to it and am presented with a number of options:

- System Restore - tells me no restore points I can use
- System Image Recovery - cannot find any images to use
- Startup Repair - as above results in the repairing disk which goes nowhere

I also have an option to install Windows which I attempt. This too fails as it tells me my partitions aren't in the correct format, or something similar

What could be going wrong here? What are my options?

Comment: Figure out what the manufacturer of your drive is, then run the diagnostic software they provide to test the health of your drive...which I suspect is failing.

Comment: "Partitions aren't in the correct format" doesn't necessarily mean the disk has failed. Could just be corrupted data. You can rebuild the partition table (wiping all partitions in the process) and reinstall Windows if you're feeling lucky, but as Twisty said, you oughtta test the disk if you suspect it.

Comment: I logged into my BIOIS diagnostics and am told "no hard drive detected, or disk controller not supported"...does this mean a replaced hard drive?